# TBO/VBO/other for opengl textures with compression and mipmaps

Tags: opengl, textures

So far, I've used:

Texture creation:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT5_EXT  , tWidth,Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,Data);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Texture usage:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
```

I am looking for efficient solutions to keep textures in memory and use it in shaders.
I've read a little about the PBO and TBO (and a few other solutions), but none of them I could find with examples of compression and mipmaps.
What do you recommend for me to choose? Which one is faster? And how it's cooperating with compression and mipmaps?

Comment: PBO's are to optimize pixel transfer, you shouldn't use them at all for storage-only purposes. Also, there is no such thing as a TBO (not for your purpose anyway), textures are opengl objects, but not buffer objects. Also, what's wrong with your current solution that it's not efficient enough?

Comment: I'm using big scene with multiple objects (each one have got minimum 3 textures). And I think there is faster solution to use these textures.
I read about PBO/TBO and in most cases there is performance impact. So I'm want to use something like this to make my engine faster (also using compression and mipmaps)

Comment: There isn't, texture objects are all you've got for storing textures, there are some advanced methods with buffer objects, but these are usually not for traditional texture usage. Also, graphics performance depends a lot on your application, don't just base your implementation on random reads (certainly if they recommend PBO's for texture storage :s). Determine your bottleneck first (e.g. measure it), start optimizing then.

Comment: I thought that by using buffers, the driver has direct access to the data texture, so everything goes faster. And how about changing  textures? (eg if all do not fit in memory?) Texture objects (form, which I gave at the top)  will continue to be a reasonable solution or then I should have fun with the buffers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought that by using buffers, the driver has direct access to the data texture, so everything goes faster.

This is the root of your problem.

When you call `glTexImage2D`, you are telling OpenGL to [allocate storage for the texture object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage). After this call, the texture has *storage* for that image data. It's like calling `malloc`, only for texture memory. The texture is not trying to read from the memory pointer you provided anymore (not after the call); you can (and generally should) delete it. The texture has that data now, *internally*.

> And how about changing textures? (eg if all do not fit in memory?)

Allocating *more* memory (the buffer objects you're talking about) won't make it more likely to fit into memory. If you're out of memory, you're out of memory; doing more allocations is not helpful.

More importantly, buffer objects are subject to the *same* issues with memory as textures; if the driver feels like it, it will remove them from GPU memory. So you're not gaining anything. So buffer object storage is not different from texture object storage.

Most importantly of all, *PBOs and TBOs don't work that way.*

"Pixel buffer object" is nothing more than a way to [asynchronously copy pixel data *into* or *out of* a texture's storage](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object). After the copying is complete, the buffer has *no association* with the texture anymore. Unless you're dynamically modifying the texture's contents, PBOs have little to do with overall texture performance.

[Buffer textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture) are a way to use a buffer object as the storage for a texture. But buffer textures are a [different texture *type*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Theory); they are as different from 2D textures as 2D textures are different from 3D textures. Buffer textures can't be mipmapped, cannot have array layers, cannot have filtering or any sampling parameters at all, can only use a [very limited set of image formats](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture#Image_formats) (and none of them are *compressed*), and they can only be accessed with `texelFetch` and its ilk. They are one-dimensional (but not 1D textures).

Buffer textures are little more than a way for a shader to just directly read from a linear array of GPU memory. You cannot simply *replace* a 2D texture with a buffer texture; you'd have to redesign your shaders and everything.

All in all, you seem to be misunderstanding a lot about OpenGL.